# Rails & Devise: How to render login page without a layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know this is probably a simple question, but I'm still trying to figure [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) out...

I want to `render :layout => false` on my login page; how can I do this with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)?

Comment: Also for future reference and a multitude of other options: in the devise wiki: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can subclass the controller and configure the router to use that:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout false
end
```

And in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

You need to move the session views to this controller too.

**OR** make a method in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  layout :layout

  private

  def layout
    # only turn it off for login pages:
    is_a?(Devise::SessionsController) ? false : "application"
    # or turn layout off for every devise controller:
    devise_controller? && "application"
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks; your second method was just what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that really helped me. However, only this line worked for me `is_a?(Devise::SessionsController) ? false : "application"`

Comment: the second check should be `!devise_controller? && "application"` notice the `not` there. But otherwise this works like a charm :)

Comment: Instead of assuming that all other controllers will use the "application" layout, it's probably better to return `nil`, which according to the [rails 4 docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout), will use "default layout behavior with inheritance".

Comment: Not sure if this is still up to date (7 years later hah) but neither of these suggestions work for me.

Answer (score 37):

You can also create a sessions.html.erb file in app/views/layouts/devise.  That layout will then be used for just the sign in screen.

Comment: Thanks!! Though I think this is not actually answering the question, it was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 8):

By using the devise_controller? helper you can determine when a Devise controller is active and respond accordingly. To have Devise use a separate layout to the rest of your application, you could do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

create a devise.html.erb file in your views/layouts

So if its a device controller will render the devise layout else the application layout

from: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts