# Rails 3, Devise: Using different layout for signup, login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, devise

I want to render a different layout for signup and login pages.

[There's s similar thread that deals with this problem, but it's not exactly the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412018/rails-devise-how-to-render-login-page-without-a-layout)

I need to be able to render different layout just for signup and login pages only, not all the other actions in a controller.

under `users/registrations_controller.rb`

```rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    render :layout => "auth"
  end
end
```

My routes

```rb
MasterCard::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }, :path => "users", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", :to => "users/sessions#new"
    # post "logout", :to => "users/sessions"
  end

  root :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/about' => 'pages#about'
end
```

This is the error I get when i  go to sign up page.

`undefined method`errors' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do you mean to subclass `Devise::RegistrationsController` and not `Devise::SessionsController`?

Overriding devise controller actions seems a little hairy. You can avoid this in your case by just overriding the default layout that `RegistrationsController` uses:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout "auth"
end
```

---

As for why you're getting that particular error:

You're redefining the `new` action in what I'm assuming should be `Devise::RegistationsController` which has the following definition:

```
def new
  resource = build_resource({})
  respond_with resource
end
```

It sets a `resource` which is then referenced in the devise helper method `devise_error_messages!`:

```
def devise_error_messages!
  return "" if resource.errors.empty?
  ...
end
```

which is used in the default devise "sign_up" template, `users/registrations/new.html.erb`:

```
...
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, ...) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
...
```

You see that error because you didn't define `resource`.